# 2-player Android game, what to use as client besides phone?

Tags: android, testing, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

If you have one phone and need to use Google Cloud Messaging, what would you use as client nbr 2? Chrome seems awkward, the simulator is terribly slow. Can you use a Python script as gcm client? I didnt quite understand how to use gcm-client, if it could receive push notifications or not. Can it?

Answer (score 1):

Only an Android application can serve as GCM client. So if you only have one phone, you'll have to use the simulator.

Another (awkward) solution you might try is to install two instances of your application on the same phone. That would require to have two builds of your app with different package names (so that your device will treat them as different applications). Each will register to GCM and get its own registration ID. Then each app can send GCM messages to the other.

Comment: Good idea. However there is at least a developers mode for Chrome apps where you can receive GCM notifications.

Comment: @user3591115 I'm not familiar enough with GCM for Chrome, and I'm not sure if it can interact with GCM for Android, so I can't help you there.